# codeigniter and tcpdf returns blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I'd like to have a page be exported as PDF in codeIgniter. I managed to install the TCPDF library following the instructions from: [TCPDF Integration](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/TCPDF-Integration) and now my controller looks like:

```
class Mycontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){

            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library("Pdf");
    }

    //make pdf
    public function pdf(){

        $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
        // Add a page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $html = "<h1>Test Page</h1>";
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'I');
    }
}
```

Then, I have a link in another page as:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/myController/pdf">Export As Pdf</a></td>
```

and when I click on it, I get a blank pdf. The contents of the page are not there.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Blank page means not reported error. You should [turn error reporting on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to see the exact error.

Comment: Note: you have named your class wrong http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: You are right!  I just edited code according to your suggestion! Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @moijoune should be some thing like Mycontroller only first letter upper case on class and file name

Comment: I'll edit it again :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Reciept Pdf');
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30);
    $pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
    $pdf->setFooterMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Author');
    $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
    $pdf->Write(5, 'CodeIgniter TCPDF Integration');
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Output('reciept.pdf', 'I');
```